# Time Machine preferences being ignored

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I have partitioned a 1TB external drive into three independent drives i.e. iTunes, Docs, Video. In *Time Machine* I have set the Preferences to only back up the internal drive (which contains my apps, settings, etc - a total of 45.58 GB). When the 1TB partitioned drive is on, *Time Machine* tries to back up all three of them + my internal drive resulting in the typical "too large" error message.

**NOTE**: Even when turned on, the other three drives don't even show up in the "Options" window where you "Exclude these items from back-ups". They do, however, show up in the "Select Disk" window.

When the 1T partitioned drive is off, *Time Machine* performs as expected i.e. backs up only the internal drive.

Is there a way of ensuring that only the internal drive is backed up?

Comment: I cannot reproduce these conditions (I have an external drive with a data partition which is excluded from TM's settings, which shares the same physical drive as the TM backup). I have voted this question up, though.

Comment: How is your external drive connected? For me (10.7.1) TimeMachine automatically adds any attached USB drive to the exclude list (and I cannot remove those entries). This might be different for FireWire drives though...